# How to use the erlang-server stubs from OpenAPI generator?

Tags: erlang, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I am currently trying to develop a REST API using Erlang. I used OpenAPI (Swagger) to define the API and wanted to use their [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) to create the stubs and some helper code. This also works and some code is generated, but I cannot find any documentation on what I have to do from there.

For the explanation of my problem, I will refer to their [sample output from code generation for erlang-server](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/samples/server/petstore/erlang-server).

I have two main problems at the moment:

- I cannot find an entry point into the code (e.g. a `init/0` or `start/0` function)
- I am not sure which function I have to implement to execute my code on each endpoint. I think that I have to implement `handle_request`, but the execution path seems a bit weird to me.

### Which function to implement

In [openapi_router](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/samples/server/petstore/erlang-server/src/openapi_router.erl) they define `openapi_pet_handler` to be the handler for `'AddPet'`. In [that module](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/samples/server/petstore/erlang-server/src/openapi_pet_handler.erl), there is a function called `handle_request_json`, which tries to populate the request and in case of OK executes `openapi_logic_handler:handle_request(LogicHandler, ...)`.

`openapi_logic_handler:handle_request(Handler, ...)` takes that handler and executes `Handler:handle_request(OperationID, Req, Context).`. This leads me to the conclusion, that I probably have to implement `openapi_pet_handler:handle_request` with my custom code.

### How to start the server

I checked the code and it seems to use `cowboy` as a web server. At least it includes dependencies to `cowboy` in the generated `openapi.app.src`. However, in `rebar.config` there is no reference to cowboy.

In the cowboy tutorial, they use erlang.mk to build their project. This allows them to run the code with `make run`. With rebar this does not seem to be possible. I did not find a specific command for rebar to start a program. You seem to have to know the entrypoint (init function) if you use rebar.

However, I am not able to find any function that looks like it could be an init function in the generated stub code.

### Summary

Can somebody explain what has to be done to use the stub generated by openapi-generator for erlang-server? Do I have to setup my own cowboy project and then somehow link the stubs into it? If yes, how?

Comment: Please open an issue via https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/new so that the community can help you out.

Comment: Cross-posted with further details about what I tried and didn't work out: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/1281